# How to compare table in mysql along with PHP for an Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am developing an Android application. I have two tables in my database. One is for maintaining the list of registered users(contains all details such as user id, name etc) and the other is for storing the list of downloaded files by their user id.

Lets assume a user searches for a particular file in my app. The list of files that are downloaded by a user are already stored in a table. How will I return the specific user id who has the same file.

[Table 1 for Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH8mC.jpg)
[Table 2 for users and their downloaded file link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KArjN.jpg)

Comment: Can you upload an example of your tables layout?

Comment: I have uploaded the table screenshots :)

Comment: First, I suggest you change your database layout. Add 'id' of 'users' in your 'downloads' table. Do not use the name as the 'id' in your 'downloads' table

Comment: Ok will do that. How do I get the user list? :P

Comment: SELECT d.id, u.name FROM downloads d LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id WHERE d.link = 'linkhere'

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it

Comment: Thanks a lot Svekke. It works. ;)

Comment: Can you upvote my answer? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! i tried to but people with less than 15 reputation won't be able to publicly vote

Comment: Hey Svekke! for the above SQL query ending with d.link = 'linkhere' This is for a constant link. I want the link to be passed from EditText in Android Studio. After receiving that value(link) how will I make the comparison like above. The earlier query you told me works fine for constant links. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you change your database layout.

Add 'id' of 'users' in your 'downloads' table. Do not use the name as the 'id' in your 'downloads' table.

Then run following query:

> SELECT d.id, u.name FROM downloads d LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id WHERE d.link = 'linkhere'